# Center align 'circle' on a vertical line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to display a vertical line and a circle positioned to the center of the vertical line. [My Workings are found in the codepen project here](https://codepen.io/shaill11/pen/NWpKGZL).

At the moment, the dot is found on top of the vertical line, But I need it to be positioned at the center. Further, the height of the vertical line should be the height of the `<td>`. How can I do this.

```css
.d {
  line-height: .5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.d::before {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  content: '';
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: .1em;
  height: 4em;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -6em;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="d">
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

It should display as shown in the diagram. The circle should move to the center of the vertical line.

[image]

Comment: you have duplicate widths and heights. What's the desired width and height?

Answer (score 1):

add this css in `.d:before`

```css
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
```

and add `top: 2em;` in `.d`

Comment: It shifts the line up, and not the Circle center.

Comment: @Illep I have updated my answer, you could try it.